# Laravel URL handling from database

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

In Laravel, how would I handle the route if it was generated dynamically? What im trying to do is give the user the ability to create pages on a website so say they wanted to create /about but that isn't listed in the routes file because they would be adding this in through an admin panel. I am trying to figure out how will I make it so I can get the full URL, see if it is a page that already exists in the route file, if it doesn't then check the database to see if that name exists for a page and if it does show the content from that page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve dynamic routing, you could do something along the lines of:

```
Route::get('/{pageName}', function($pageName) {
    // Do your logic here to determine if the page is in the database, or a file.
});
```

Take a look at the Laravel documentation on [Routing Parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters) to see what else you can do with them. In my opinion, the Laravel routing system is very clean and extremely powerful.

**Update**

One way of doing multiple routes would be like so:

```
Route::get('/{pageName}/{subPage}', function($pageName, $subPage) {
    // Do your logic here to determine if the page is in the database, or a file.
});
```

You can get into far more advanced URL structures as well by utilizing regular expressions. It's all documented in the link provided above.

Comment: I'd take it a step further and do: `Route::get('/{username}/{pageName}', function($username, $pageName) {` or something to prevent collisions.. Sorry I mis-read this as he wanted different users in the user base to have access to create routes.

Comment: @Blake You absolutely could, but that would be up to the OP and how they set up their system. The answer given shows how they can use Laravel routes for dynamic pages in the utmost simplicity.

Comment: Thanks guys. This gives me the starting point I needed. One other quick question that comes up as I am working through this using your answer, what if there are multiple pieces to this like: domain.com/first/second. How could I pull all of that?

Comment: @Scott Take a look at the Routing Parameters link I posted in the answer. You are able to add additional, either optional or required variables to the routes. I have also updated my answer to include an example of the /first/second request.

Comment: Thanks @RhapX I appreciate the help

Comment: @Scott No problem, glad to have helped.